# How to get the DOM properties from event.target, so I can compare them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to find out if my click is on a specific Highcharts chart. I cannot use the click event on the chart, since the area is in the title, not on the chart itself, and Highcharts does not support click events on anything beyond the plotted area.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    var clickedElement = event.target;
    if (clickedElement == "chart_1")
        console.log('yes');
    console.log(clickedElement);
});
```

I save the event.target in a variable; then I would like to check if what I clicked is a specific chart (I have multiple charts on the same page, each one in its div).

This is what I get as output of console.log; when I click on a Highchart:

```
<rect x=​"0" y=​"0" width=​"880" height=​"150" strokeWidth=​"0" rx=​"15" ry=​"15" fill=​"url(#highcharts-2)​" class=​" highcharts-background">​</rect>​
```

I would like to check the fill and see which chart am I clicking on, to then trigger an event.

I tried to use a search by string, but it fails since the object returned from event.target is a DOM (from what I understand, I am just starting with this); so how can I access the values in the variable, and compare them, so I can look for a specific value for the class or for the fill?

EDIT:

Thanks Adeneo!
The solution that works is the one using .getAttribute. This will return "yes", when I click on a chart that has in the fill "url(#highcharts-2)"

```
$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    var clickedElement = event.target;
    if (clickedElement.getAttribute('fill') == "url(#highcharts-2)")
        console.log('yes');
});
```

All the others didn't work when I tried them, the comparison would always fail; this is the only one that works. Thanks again

Comment: `clickedElement.getAttribute('fill')`

Comment: Bingo; with this I can extract just the fill attribute, and the string comparison will work in my if condition. Thanks! Please post it as answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**getAttribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)

```
clickedElement.getAttribute('fill')
```

Answer (score 0):

just wrap it in jQuery and use prop() to get property:

```
$(clickedElement).prop("fill")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works too (I was not assigning the variable correctly, so I was getting undefined).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery version < jQuery 1.6, use

```
$(clickedElement).attr("fill")
```

Other wise for jQuery versions > jQuery 1.6 use

```
$(clickedElement).prop("fill")
```

Comment: Thanks, tried both and it didn't work; I would get, as mentioned in the other response, a undefined. BTW I use jQuery 1.7.1. Thanks

Comment: have you consoled clickedElement. what does it print in console ??

Comment: Ok, my bad; I didn't assigned the event.target first, so obviously, the variable was empty and returned undefined. .prop works fine too. Thanks!